# Excel SUMIFS Function to Sum Only for Dates In a Certain Month and Year?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a range of dates in a worksheet that run across an entire row in format mm/dd/yyyy. As part of a SUMIF function I'd like to add up all the "points" that fall within a month/year combination (which would be specified via a cell reference). Any thoughts on how to do this? Should I instead try an If statement nested within SUM?

Comment: just book end, you want all the dates that are greater than or equal to the 1st of the month/year and less than the last day of the month/year.

Comment: Are you able to make a criteria row or column which is the date range (e.g. monthly or weekly). SUMIF uses a criteria so this might possibly work.

Comment: SUMPRODUCT is also a suggestion, do you have a sample?

Answer (score 2):

As @Scott Craner said, you can bookend the first and last dates of the month and then use a SUMIFS to add up all the "points".

Here's a simple example with a value of 1 in column B for every day in a month.  Enter any date D3, and the formula in E3 will add up all the values in column B if the date in column A is between the first and last days of the month.

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&DATE(YEAR(D3),MONTH(D3),1),A:A,"<="&EOMONTH(D3,0))
```

If you're using a text field in D3 instead of a date, you'd have to add DATEVALUE() to the formula to convert it to a date before extracting the first and last days of the month.

[image]

And here it is with the dates transposed into columns instead of rows.  Same idea, but maybe harder to see in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This works exactly how I'd like it! Somewhat of a tangential question: can a SUMIF use an array as its first argument?

Comment: @fruityflex - Regrettably, no.

Comment: I believe in my particular case, since the summation is all values within an array meeting certain criteria, I'd need to do a SUMProduct instead. How would the same argument be written there?

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(B:B,--(MONTH(A:A)=MONTH(D3)),--(YEAR(A:A)=YEAR(D3)))